# Extra space added between widgets when image is right aligned

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying the following layout,in that I want to shift image to right but because linear layout is vertically oriented extra spaces are added between textview and image.
I dont want to use Relative layout because I am editing someone else's code and it is just the part of the code.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llSpouse"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_spouse"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="SPOUSE"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />



            <com.ypomumbai.utills.CircularNetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_picture"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSpouseFirstName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="First Name"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSpouseLastName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Last Name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSpousedesignation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_last_name"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="MD and CEO" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSpouseCompnayName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_designation"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Text" />

          </View>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone help on this.
How to shift image to right without getting extra spaces.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Vertical linear layout every view will occupy the total row space. So add the margin bottom property to your `com.ypomumbai.utills.CircularNetworkImageView` with the height of that view.(negative margin will remove the space occupied by this view)

```
<com.ypomumbai.utills.CircularNetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_picture"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-80dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand if you don't want to use a RelativeLayout at all, but I post a sample of code that should work with a relative layout and without breaking the rest :

```
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSpouse"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_spouse"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="SPOUSE"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvSpouseFirstName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="First Name"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvSpouseLastName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Last Name"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvSpousedesignation"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_last_name"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="MD and CEO"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvSpouseCompnayName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_designation"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Text"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_picture"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"/>
        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

which renders the following :

[image]

**EDIT**

You can have the same render without RelativeLayout with the following xml :

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSpouse"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_spouse"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="SPOUSE"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvSpouseFirstName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="First Name"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvSpouseLastName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Last Name"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvSpousedesignation"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="MD and CEO"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvSpouseCompnayName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Text"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_picture"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"/>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...but it is coming at bottom